# Why migration Re-Created when migration file already exist and database updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.1

We are working with two team and one team check-in his migration file and other update his database with and when second team create any migration that time fist team model property also adding in new migration,so i am not sure why this happening when migration file and database also available and updated. using code first approach in .net core 3.1 and please help me how to fixed this issue.

```
public DbSet<Order> tblOrder { get; set; }
public DbSet<Variable> tblVariableRules { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Map all tables to model.
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("tblUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("tblRoles");
    }
```

Comment: hard to tell without seeing actual files, migrations, snapshots. most likely snapshot is not up to date in your version control system, when someone creates new migration

Comment: thanks for reply i attached my code what we are working currently please suggest me if need to any changes with this.

Comment: i mean when you invoke `dotnet ef migrations add` - EF uses snapshot of database, which is separate file and creates migration file with new changes based on a models from code-first. this code is not really helpful, would be easier to find issue if you attached migration and snapshot files that are causing errors

Comment: in some environments with really bad database schema i used package called `FluentMigrator`. it allows to use `IF NOT EXISTS` construction, so if migration is already applied, it won't do anything. The downside is that you have to use C# to write migrations by hand. Maybe it will be the option in your problem, if you cant resolve it